# ubuntu linux server: create a gitlab user, with only access to a specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, security, gitlab-ci

I have a question:

is it possible to create a 'gitlab' user, with only access to a specific directory, like:

```
/var/www/my-website/releases/
```

background:
when I create a new user with the name 'gitlab', I can read for example /etc/nginx/sites-availabe... but for security reasons I think its better, the user has only access to a specifiy directory and should not be able to read configs etc...
In the end I want to do with this user a git clone ... triggered by the gitlab ci.

What I tried so far: chmod 640 for a special file, than the 'gitlab' user can not read it, but I think I can't do this for the whole '/etc/' direcory without getting other problems, right?

Thanks
Bert